# Postman vs PHP cURL response time

Tags: php, curl, postman, response-time

I have an API call and it is taking 0.5 to 1 second in POSTMAN whereas the same API call taking 7 to 12 seconds with PHP cURL and its response time is totally abnormal. How should I increase this response time?

My code :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$voicefile = $argv[1];

$auth = $argv[2];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions',

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',

  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,

  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,

  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',

  CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE => 1,

  CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE => 2, // Time in seconds before sending keepalive probes

  CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL => 1, // Time in seconds between keepalive probes

  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,

 

  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('model' => 'whisper-1','file'=> new CURLFILE('/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/restaurant/'.$voicefile.'.wav')),

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

'Authorization: Bearer '.$auth ,

'cache-control: no-cache' // ,

  ),

));

echo "Seconds before API Call :". time()."\n";

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;

echo "\n Seconds after API Call:" . time()."\n";

?>
```

Comment: Does postman really upload the entire file? How large are your wav file? Do you use the same file when executing the request in postman? I am think wav files are usually very large and therefor it is not that surprising if it takes some time to upload it?

Comment: I think `curl` is not slow as you think it is. It's about steps to perform in order to return you a response including understanding of how `lookup` is working depending on software that you are using. Try to use IP address of the host instead of domain name(do resolving instead of curl for example and compare diff again). Try to convert you request from postman into `curl` format and run it with `trace` and `trace  --time` options to see on which point it slows. And then you will have bigger picture and diff which you asking about with understanding why one thing is fast and another is slow.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?